# how to set different font size to text of button name in storyboard

Tags: ios, uibutton, storyboard, facebook-sdk-4.0

I want to make application in which i want to make a login screen. It has button having name "Log inn with Facebook". I want font size of Facebook greater than Log in with. How can I set it in main storyboard?Can anyone plz help me?

Comment: select the text you want to increase the font. and change the font size in Attribute Inspector

Answer (score 11):

Follow these steps-

1.Select button

2.Change its type to custom in **Attributes inspector**

3.Change its title from **Plain** to **Attributed**

4.Change the part of title which you want to be set bold

[image]

Comment: Already did this, and worked well in storyboard. But if I run, it wont work. Still plain text. Any ideas?

Comment: Nope, don't touch that button programmatically.

Comment: @SonicMaster you are setting it for default state right? and type is custom?

Comment: I delete the button, re-adding and following your way, and it works! Thank you @sanman!

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to have a `UIView` with two different `UILabel` as subviews ( your "Log in with" label and your "Facebook" label ).

Then, above this `UIView` you could have a `UIButton` with a white background and an alpha equal to 0.01 so the button would be touchable but invisible.

This `UIButton` would be the functional part of your UI.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableAttributedString *titleText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Login with Facebook"];
[yourbutton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];

// Set the font to bold from the beginning of the string to the ","
[titleText addAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] forKey:NSFontAttributeName] range:NSMakeRange(0, 10)];


// Set the attributed string as the buttons' title text
[yourbutton setAttributedTitle:titleText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Instead of creating NSAttributedString create NSMutableAttributedString then you can just set the string like this.